# Why is the data being added to the same table twice?

Tags: database, postgresql, flutter, dart, logic

I have a database that has a queues table that holds queues names and ids, and the two queue tables (queue 1, and queue 2).
now i have a function that is supposed to add orders to the right queue, but it's only adding to the second queue and i'm already using a for loop to change the queue that should be used.

here's the code

```
for (int i = 0; i < tmpQueuesIds.length; i++){
      await http.post(GlobalState.ADDTOQUEUE, body: {
        'queueId': tmpQueuesIds[i].toString(),
        'timeinmin': tmpTimes[tmpQueuesIds[i]].toString(),
        'resId': _globalState.get('resId').toString(),
        'userId': userId.toString(),
      });
      print("QueueId: " + tmpQueuesIds[i].toString());
      print("OrderTime: " + tmpTimes[tmpQueuesIds[i]].toString());
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500));
    }
```

and here's the output:

```
I/flutter ( 3238): QueueId: 1
I/flutter ( 3238): OrderTime: 6
I/flutter ( 3238): QueueId: 2
I/flutter ( 3238): OrderTime: 10
```

as you can see i have two queues and the values are being changed, but it's inserting the value 10 twice to the queue 2, it should be inserting value 6 to queue 1 and value 10 to queue 2.

and here's the api code

```
try {
    router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {

        queueId = req.body.queueId;
        resId = req.body.resId;
        timeinmin = req.body.timeinmin;
        userId = req.body.userId;
        var orderId;

        sqlQuery = `SELECT id FROM orders where userid = ${userId} and isdone = false`;

        con.query(sqlQuery, (err, rows) => {
            try {
                lastIndex = rows['rows'].length - 1;
                orderId = rows['rows'][lastIndex]['id'];
            } catch{
                console.log('something wrong with setting orderId or lastIndex value in addToQueue.js');
            }

            if (!err) {
                sqlQuery2 = `SELECT name FROM queues where id = ${queueId}`;
                try {
                    con.query(sqlQuery2, function (err, rows) {
                        try {
                            queueName = rows['rows'][0]['name'];
                        } catch{
                            console.log('something wrong with setting queueName value in addToQueue.js');

                        }

                        if (!err) {

                            sqlQuery2 = `INSERT INTO ${queueName} (timeinmin, resid, orderid) VALUES(${timeinmin}, ${resId}, ${orderId})`;

                            try {
                                con.query(sqlQuery2, function (err, rows) {

                                    if (!err) {
                                        res.sendStatus(201);
                                        console.log('added to queue');
                                    } else {
                                        console.error("Failed to add to queue");
                                        console.log(err);
                                        res.sendStatus(202);
                                    }
                                });
                            } catch{
                                console.log('Something went down.');
                            }
                        } else {
                            console.error("Failure");
                            console.log(err);
                            res.sendStatus(202);
                        }
                    });
                } catch{
                    console.log('Something went down.');
                }
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                res.sendStatus(202);
            }
        })
    });
} catch{
    console.log('Error');
}
```

help me please, thanks.

Comment: The problem might not be here. Could we see the backend code?

Comment: have you got you database in google cloud?

Comment: @dshukertjr yeah okay i'll post the api code

Comment: @delmin no it's on my local pc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any problems with your code.

My advice is to try restarting your IDEs and if the problem still persists try restarting your whole computer.